# How to add the borders to the UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I want to have the following look of the `UIBarButtonItem`:

[image]

And [I have this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i7fO.png)

(save it because it has the same color as StackOverflow background so you're unable to see it right here)

How can I add the borders like in the first image to the `UIBarButtonItem`? Is it possible without drawing it by myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When i was in the same situation i use segment control with the image to show boarder.

Comment: @Jageen Is there any more elegant solution to do it? I am unable to create segmented control with one element btw

Comment: sorry i check my code,i done exactly like kampai suggest.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61143130/6108739

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more solution is that create `UIButton` object and play with it's layer property.

I have done some basic setup which looks like blue image as shown in question:

[image]

Add below code in `viewDidLoad()` method, also include `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;

button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
button.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
button.layer.shadowOpacity = .9;
button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
button.layer.masksToBounds = NO;


UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
```

### Add more gradient effects

I did found one git help **[YIInnerShadowView](https://github.com/inamiy/YIInnerShadowView)** have a look, it's very useful.

I have use these classes to make gradient and shadow looks like blue image. Able to get much similarity with that image. You can have do more customisation on these classes to get desire accuracy.

[image]

Add this library to project, import `#import "YIInnerShadowView.h"` and add code to `viewDidLoad()`

```
YIInnerShadowView *innerView = [[YIInnerShadowView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
innerView.shadowRadius = 1.5;
innerView.cornerRadius = 5;
innerView.shadowMask = YIInnerShadowMaskAll;

innerView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.3843 green:0.6235 blue:0.8156 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
innerView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[innerView addSubview:button];

UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:innerView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
```

Also have done little modification in `YIInnerShadowLayer.m` class:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        self.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;
        self.shouldRasterize = YES;

        // Standard shadow stuff
        [self setShadowColor:[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
        [self setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, 1.0f)];
        [self setShadowOpacity:1.0f];
        [self setShadowRadius:5];

        // Causes the inner region in this example to NOT be filled.
        [self setFillRule:kCAFillRuleEvenOdd];

        self.shadowMask = YIInnerShadowMaskAll;

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Am I able to do it via Interface Builder?

Comment: Not sure. But looking at `UIBarButtonItem` properties in Nib, it's not gives us more customisation for it. So it is better to go with programatically.

Comment: This one is the right way to do it. I am afraid you cannot do it via Interface Builder. You just simply have to put it in you `-(void)viewDidLoad` just after `[super viewDidLoad];` & you are good to go. Just add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file you are using this solution.

Comment: @RichaSharma - `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` is notable point. Thanks

Comment: Am I able to do it via Interface Builder? why not? User runtime defined attributes?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it gives the different result -- http://i.imgur.com/agIcTOK.png As you see, there's no shadow and it doesn't look like in the first image

Comment: Here you need to add gradient to button for exactly same visual effect. Let me try and i'll keep you update.

Comment: Thanks! I'm waiting for you solution

Comment: @FrozenHeart I tried as much as possible to make it similar with your one. Check edited answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you give me your Skype, btw? I want to share my new questions on StackOverflow with you

Comment: We will start chat on StackOverflow on monday.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61143130/6108739