# How to apply borders and corner radius to UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have programatically created a toolbar to which I have added a UIBarButtonItem.

This is what is currently looks like:

[image: UIBarButtonItem]

I want the the button to have a border and a corner radius(curved corners). 
How will the same be implemented?

UIBarButtonItem Implementation code:

```
let okBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "donePressed:")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can find the UIView associated with the UIBarButtonItem, you can modify the `UIView.layer`. But, finding the `UIView` is not made easy. I used the technique from [Figure out UIBarButtonItem frame in window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2994354/figure-out-uibarbuttonitem-frame-in-window) . Starting with the `navigationController.navigationBar`, which itself is a `UIView`, I recursed through the subviews, one of which will be the button I wanted. Which one? Pick your own criteria! Here's my code:

```
func recurseViews(view:UIView) {
    print("recurseViews: \(view)") // helpful for sorting out which view is which
    if view.frame.origin.x > 700 { // find _my_ button
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        view.layer.borderWidth = 2
    }
    for v in view.subviews { recurseViews(v) }
}
```

then in `viewDidAppear` (or similar)

```
recurseViews((navigationController?.navigationBar)!)
```

which is a bit of a hack but does the job:

[image: button with border]

Comment: Normally I try to stay away from using tags but this is one of those cases where assigning a tag and traverse the view hierarchy for it makes sense so you can get the specific view more reliably.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in automatic way to do this, unfortunately. You have two choices:

- You could make this a bar button item with a custom view, make that view a UIButton, and then do the usual stuff to that UIButton (which you can do because it's a view), by way of its layer (give it a border and corner radius).
- You could just draw (in code) a background image with a curved border and use that as the bar button item's image.

Answer (score 0):

I do it with a storyboard. Just add UIButton inside UiBarButtonItem. Like here [image]

And after that added a border to the UIButton 
[image]